# Regex to add comma between any character

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm relatively new to regex, so bear with me if the question is trivial. I'd like to place a comma between every letter of a string using regex, e.g.:

```
x <- "ABCD"
```

I want to get

```
"A,B,C,D"
```

It would be nice if I could do that using `gsub`, `sub` or related on a vector of strings of arbitrary number of characters.

I tried

```
> sub("(\\w)", "\\1,", x)
[1] "A,BCD"
> gsub("(\\w)", "\\1,", x)
[1] "A,B,C,D,"
> gsub("(\\w)(\\w{1})$", "\\1,\\2", x)
[1] "ABC,D"
```

Comment: `trimws(gsub("", ",", x),,",")`

Comment: @Tom I changed "colon" to "comma" in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
> gsub("(.)(?=.)", "\\1,", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "A,B,C,D"
```

The `(.)(?=.)` regex matches any char capturing it into Group 1 (with `(.)`) that must be followed with any single char (`(?=.)`) is a positive lookahead that requires a char immediately to the right of the current location).

Vriations of the solution:

```r
> gsub("(.)(?!$)", "\\1,", x, perl=TRUE)
## Or with stringr:
## stringr::str_replace_all(x, "(.)(?!$)", "\\1,")
[1] "A,B,C,D"
```

Here, `(?!$)` fails the match if there is an end of string position.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/Fe5iAN):

```r
x <- "ABCD"
gsub("(.)(?=.)", "\\1,", x, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "A,B,C,D"
gsub("(.)(?!$)", "\\1,", x, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "A,B,C,D"
stringr::str_replace_all(x, "(.)(?!$)", "\\1,")
# => [1] "A,B,C,D"
```

Comment: ah. Thanks! I thought it was something about the lookahead, but I didn't manage to make it work. Thanks also for the explanation, this is realy helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
x <- 'ABCD'
gsub('\\B', ',', x, perl = T)
```

Prints:

```
[1] "A,B,C,D"
```

---

Might have misread the query; OP is looking to add comma's between **letters** only. Therefor try:

```
gsub('(\\p{L})(?=\\p{L})', '\\1,', x, perl = T)
```

- `(\p{L})` - Match any kind of letter from any language in a 1st group;
- `(?=\p{L})` - Positive lookahead to match as per above.

We can use the backreference to this capture group in the replacement.

Comment: ah, right: *‘⁠\B⁠’ matches the empty string provided it is not at an edge of a word*; another helpful symbol.

Comment: @Tom, I do have a followup question though. Do you wish to add a comma between **all** characters? Including comma's itself? For example, what is your desired output for say `Hello,12&4`. Though `\B` works for the current sample data it may cause unexpected results.

Comment: hehe, nice. But no, not in this instance

Comment: @Tom so `\B` might not be what you are looking for as it would also match positions that are not exclusively between letters. I interpreted your question wrong at first but edited my answer to include a way to match the position between letters only.

Comment: ok *⁠\p{xx}⁠’ and ‘⁠\P{xx}⁠’ which match characters with and without property ‘⁠xx⁠’ respectively* whereas `L` stands for "letter"?!

Comment: @Tom, yes. See [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) list for referencing.

Comment: Nice one and imho best fitting answer yet, especially the second part.

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex friendly answer:

```r
paste(strsplit(x, "")[[1]], collapse = ",")
#[1] "A,B,C,D"
```

Comment: thanks! I came up with this as well, but I really need to sharpen my `regex`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use positive look behind and look ahead to assert there is a preceding and a following character:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, "(?<=.)(?=.)", ",")
[1] "A,B,C,D"
```